# Optimizing Django Admin Search by 'external_id' for Large Datasetsop

Tags: django

I'm facing performance issues when searching for records by the 'external_id' field in the Django Admin on a large dataset. The 'external_id' is a unique identifier for each record in my model. I've already added a HashIndex for this field, but it's still slow.

What can I do to optimize the search performance in this specific scenario? Are there any other indexing techniques or Django-specific optimizations that can help speed up the search operation?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to improve the performance of searching by 'external_id' in the Django Admin, especially on large datasets. Thank you!

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import HashIndex
from django.db import models

class SocialIds(models.Model):
    """Model for social network identifiers of a user."""

    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.Profile',
        related_name='socials',
        on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='User Profile',
    )
    service_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        verbose_name='Social Network Name',
    )
    external_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='External Identifier',
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Social Network Identifier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Social Network Identifiers'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=[
                    'service_name',
                    'external_id',
                ], name='unique_social_service_name_external_id_ids',
            ),
        ]
        indexes = [
            HashIndex(
                fields=['external_id'],
                name='social_ids_external_idx',
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.profile)
```

```
@admin.register(SocialIds)
class SocialIDsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('profile', 'service_name')
    list_filter = ('service_name',)
    raw_id_fields = ('profile',)
    search_fields = ['profile__nickname', 'external_id']
    fields = ('profile', 'service_name')
```

I'd like to obtain an optimal query time for searching in the admin panel, especially on large datasets, to ensure that the service doesn't crash

Comment: Why does your service hinge on being able to search by external IDs in the admin panel?

Comment: The Django `ModelAdmin` will, for text-like fields, use an `ILIKE `%foo%` so a substring match, so a hash will not make a significant difference.

Comment: Normal indexes only improve lookup performance but won't help with free text searches. You should investigate using something like a [`GinIndex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#ginindex) (assuming PostgreSQL) and integrating full text search features of Django with the Admin search. Not a trivial task, but doable.

Comment: check `profile__nickname` may be it is the reason for slowness.